# C - dynamic array in a struct - crash after reallocation

Tags: c, struct, malloc, realloc

I am new to C and trying to have a dynamic array inside a struct, to which I need to add a dynamic number of items.

If I use `malloc` with a big number (like +100000) when initialising the container, the program works fine.

However, if I just allocate `sizeof(struct ...)` memory, and then try to reallocate using `realloc`, the program crashes when I try to add new item to the array. Even if I add +1000000 size when reallocating, it still crashes, while the same size works if I use it when allocating in the first place.

Cut down code to display my problem:

```
struct Station {
    char name[100];
};

struct StationContainer {
    int numberOfStations;
    struct Station *stations[];
};

struct StationContainer *makeContainer() {
    struct StationContainer *new;
    // If I add +1000000 in size here, the program works fine
    new = (struct StationContainer *) malloc(sizeof(struct StationContainer));

    if (new == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "makeContainer: out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    new->numberOfStations = 0;

    return new;
}

int main(int argc, int argv[]) {

    // Initialize the container
    struct StationContainer *container;
    container = makeContainer();

    // Add new station to container
    struct Station *new;
    new = (struct Station *) malloc(sizeof(struct Station));

    if (new == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "makeStation: out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    strcpy(new->name, name);

    // Add to the container
    // Even if I add +1000000 here, it still crashes below when I add new item
    container = (struct StationContainer *) realloc(container, sizeof(struct StationContainer) + 1000000);

    if (container == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "makeStation: container out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    container->stations[container->numberOfStations] = new;
    container->numberOfStations++;


}
```

**EDIT1:**
The problem in my cut down version was spotted, however, once I returned to full version, I was still getting the error. I got the `container out of memory`. That was because my `container->numberOfStations` was wildly big after first increment for some reason.

My full code at:
[codepad](http://codepad.org/eV8EhJpN)

The `adjacencies.txt` file contents:

```
Baker Street, Bond Street, Regent's Park
Bond Street, Marble Arch, Baker Street, Oxford Circus, Green Park
Marble Arch, Bond Street
Green Park, Bond Street, Oxford Circus, Piccadilly Circus
Regent's Park, Baker Street, Oxford Circus
Oxford Circus, Bond Street, Regent's Park, Warren Street, Tottenham Court Road, Piccadilly Circus
Piccadilly Circus, Green Park, Oxford Circus, Leicester Square, Charing Cross
Warren Street, Oxford Circus, Goodge Street
Goodge Street, Warren Street, Tottenham Court Road
Tottenham Court Road, Oxford Circus, Goodge Street, Holborn, Leicester Square
Leicester Square, Piccadilly Circus, Tottenham Court Road, Covent Garden, Charing Cross
Charing Cross, Piccadilly Circus, Leicester Square
Covent Garden, Leicester Square, Holborn
Holborn, Tottenham Court Road, Chancery Lane
Chancery Lane, Holborn
```

When I make the stations, if I leave `container->numberOfStations` unchanged, there is no problem. However, when I at least increment it once, combined with the `realloc`, it changes to huge numbers. Example output:

```
Number of stations: 0
!Station name:[Baker Street]
Number of stations: 1
!Station name:[Bond Street]
Number of stations: 4067560
makeStation: container out of memory
```

I feel like there is a small error somewhere that makes my numberOfStation change wildly even though it's supposed to increment just by one?

Comment: First note: don't cast malloc return value. Second note: calling a variable `new` is not recommended. Where is `name` declared ? `strcpy(new->name, name);`

Comment: Will change that, I was just following notes from my Uni lectures

Comment: Can you give some input and exact line where you are getting the error using `gdb` ?

Comment: `sizeof(struct StationContainer) + 1000000` makes no sense in `malloc()`/`realloc()` as you want the amount of memory allocated to be multiple sizes of `struct StationContainer` - did you mean to write `sizeof(struct StationContainer) * 1000000`

Comment: @ChrisTurner no, + 1000000 is just for debugging, showing that when I allocate memory in the first place it works, but when I try to reallocate it doesn't work. In the first place yes, it will be `sizeof(struct(Station)) * numberOfStations`

Comment: @Jarvis sorry I am new to this and not familiar with how to use gdb. And the cut down version code I have provided will show the crash without any input

Comment: It doesn't when I manually allocate memory to `name` like this : `char *name = malloc(100);` @Giedrius

Answer (score 4):

In the original version posted, `container->numberOfStations` was uninitialized.
In makeContainer you might consider using `calloc()` or `memset()` to initialize your container to zero - it works nicely when you add new items to the struct and they still should be initialized to zero.

In the current version I can spot no error, and neither can `valgrind`.  I took the liberty of declaring a `name` within the constraints of the 100 char limit.

Comment: Good eyes. didn't notice you've answered. :) deleted mine.

Comment: Good spot, I accidentally deleted that when cut down the code for this preview. I will edit it now to show how it is.

Comment: I have made another edit showing exactly how I get my error. It happens when I try to increment my `container->numberOfStations` by one. I have added a link to full code a `codepad.org` as well. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Well - look at

```
struct StationContainer {
    int numberOfStations;
    struct Station *stations[];
};
```

So `stations` is pointer

So `makeContainer` just gives it enough space for a pointer etc. You have not even allocated the memory for the pointer to have information nor initialised `numberOfStations`. It is just an uninitialised pointer

PS: Does this compile

```
   strcpy(new->name, name);
```

Cannot find the declaration for `name`

Comment: Yes he did allocate. He's pointing to `new` with that pointer.

Comment: Eh? `name` is not declared. `new->name` has memory

Comment: @Tony `container->stations` isn't defined though so you can't access any elements of it

Comment: I meant he allocated memory for `StationContainer`. For `Station` he indeed didn't. I've pointed it out in comments.

Comment: In my edited code the `container->stations` works fine, I can write and read at least 1 station from there. It's the `container->numberOfStations` that gets wildly big and therefore program runs out of memory.